# STM8 TIM1 (or TIM2) - one 5s tick after external interrupt event

Tags: sdcc, stm8

I'm trying to implement this logic in STM8S103F3:
1) Controller wait for external interurpts on GPIOC (high by default) after initialization.
2.1) external interrupt triggered: if PIN5 of GPIOC is low, turn test led on, and start timer for 5s.
2.2) external interrupt triggered: if PIN5 of GPIOC is high, turn test led off and stop timer.
3) timer interrupt triggered: turn test led off.

My code:

```
#include "stm8s.h"
#include "stm8s_gpio.h"
#include "stm8s_exti.h"
#include "stm8s_tim1.h"

void tim1_update_handler() __interrupt(11)
{
    GPIO_WriteHigh(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5);
    TIM1_ClearITPendingBit(TIM1_IT_UPDATE);
}

void portc_ext_int_handler() __interrupt(5)
{
    uint8_t state = GPIO_ReadInputData(GPIOC);
    if (state & GPIO_PIN_5) // PORTC pin 5 high, default state, button not pressed.
    {
        TIM1_SetCounter(0);
        TIM1_Cmd(ENABLE);
    }
    else // Button pressed.
    {
        GPIO_WriteLow(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5);
        TIM1_Cmd(DISABLE);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    disableInterrupts();

    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP_HIGH_FAST);
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_ALL, GPIO_MODE_IN_PU_IT);

    EXTI_DeInit();
    EXTI_SetExtIntSensitivity(EXTI_PORT_GPIOC, EXTI_SENSITIVITY_RISE_FALL);

    TIM1_TimeBaseInit(2000, TIM1_COUNTERMODE_UP, 5000, 0);
    TIM1_SelectOnePulseMode(TIM1_OPMODE_SINGLE);
    TIM1_ITConfig(TIM1_IT_UPDATE, ENABLE);

    enableInterrupts();

    while (1)
    {
        wfi();
    }
}
```

External interrupt is triggered fine, but timer interrupt does not triggers.

What i'm doing wrong with timer, and how i can gix it?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late with this,but possibly it is because of the interrupt priority, which by default is set to NOT interrupt an ISR already in progress. Changing the ITC_xxx registers allows setting these priorities so one IRQ can interrupt another, which is what you need with the timer.